# Why is the while loop in Mongodb inserting the same document several times instead of iterating through the documents?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, while-loop

I am redesigning a mongodb database so that the reviews for a product are contained within the product document instead of having separate collections for reviews and products. I created a loop that iterates through reviews and inserts them into the corresponding product document. However when querying the database later I see that if a products has more than one review instead of iterating through the reviews and inserting each one, the first review is being repeated for the amount of reviews there are.

Any help would be appreciated.

Examples of the product and review documents before update

```
// product document
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d0b6d1cd7367de7f58b4a77"),
    "p2507945_asin" : "B00005JHK9",
    "p2507945_salesRank" : {
        "Clothing" : 2416095
    },
    "p2507945_imUrl" : "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/413S4T19S8L._SY445_.jpg",
    "p2507945_categories" : [ 
        [ 
            "Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", 
            "Boys"
        ], 
        [ 
            "Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", 
            "Novelty, Costumes & More", 
            "Costumes & Accessories", 
            "Costumes", 
            "Kids & Baby", 
            "Boys"
        ]
    ],
    "p2507945_title" : "Gladiator Costume: Boy's Size 7-8"
}

// Review documents for product
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d0b70f2d7367de7f5fa1da3"),
    "p2507945_reviewerID" : "A2Y0II6CM888FO",
    "p2507945_asin" : "B00005JHK9",
    "p2507945_reviewerName" : "BAB \"BAB\"",
    "p2507945_helpful" : [ 
        3, 
        4
    ],
    "p2507945_reviewText" : "Looks cool but the plastic is very thin on the chest shield, leg and arm guards. The face plate velcroes on as does the shoulder pads which pop off too easily! Every move my son made they were coming apart! Too many pieces for an active boy to keep in place for any length of time! This costume is cheaply made for the price!We were very disappointed in it!!!",
    "p2507945_overall" : 1.0,
    "p2507945_summary" : "Gladiator Costume",
    "p2507945_unixReviewTime" : 1064966400,
    "p2507945_reviewTime" : "10 1, 2003"
}
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d0b70f2d7367de7f5fa1da4"),
    "p2507945_reviewerID" : "A2PIV63VGDZBFX",
    "p2507945_asin" : "B00005JHK9",
    "p2507945_reviewerName" : "\"dauph08\"",
    "p2507945_helpful" : [ 
        12, 
        13
    ],
    "p2507945_reviewText" : "Overall, this is a neat costume for the money and my son thinks it's pretty cool. I think there are 2 things that could have been done differently though:1. The shoulder pads fall off easily as they need to make either more velcro to hold them on or else find a different way to attach the shoulder pads (which I'm in the process of doing).2. My son was pretty disappointed that the sword pictured didn't come with the costume. For their cost of an extra buck at the most, the company should really have the matching sword included.So really, these are minor things that can be fixed and the costume is really neat and also fun for kids to play with, but sometimes it's nice to buy something without having to \"fix\" it :)",
    "p2507945_overall" : 5.0,
    "p2507945_summary" : "Not bad for the money",
    "p2507945_unixReviewTime" : 1033603200,
    "p2507945_reviewTime" : "10 3, 2002"
}
```

Code to update

```
var RvColcursor =
db.p250794_reviews.find({}, {_id : 0});
while (RvColcursor.hasNext()) {
  var nextRVDoc = RvColcursor.next();
  var ProductID = nextRVDoc.p2507945_asin;
  var RvDoccursor = db.p2507945_reviews.find({p2507945_asin : ProductID}, {_id : 0, p2507945_asin : 0});
  var nextRVDocUp = RvDoccursor.next();
  db.p2507945_products.update({p2507945_asin : ProductID}, {$push : {Reviews : nextRVDocUp}});
}
```

An example of what is being returned

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d0b6d1cd7367de7f58b4a77"),
    "p2507945_asin" : "B00005JHK9",
    "p2507945_salesRank" : {
        "Clothing" : 2416095
    },
    "p2507945_imUrl" : "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/413S4T19S8L._SY445_.jpg",
    "p2507945_categories" : [ 
        [ 
            "Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", 
            "Boys"
        ], 
        [ 
            "Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", 
            "Novelty, Costumes & More", 
            "Costumes & Accessories", 
            "Costumes", 
            "Kids & Baby", 
            "Boys"
        ]
    ],
    "p2507945_title" : "Gladiator Costume: Boy's Size 7-8",
    "Reviews" : [ 
        {
            "p2507945_reviewerID" : "A2Y0II6CM888FO",
            "p2507945_reviewerName" : "BAB \"BAB\"",
            "p2507945_helpful" : [ 
                3, 
                4
            ],
            "p2507945_reviewText" : "Looks cool but the plastic is very thin on the chest shield, leg and arm guards. The face plate velcroes on as does the shoulder pads which pop off too easily! Every move my son made they were coming apart! Too many pieces for an active boy to keep in place for any length of time! This costume is cheaply made for the price!We were very disappointed in it!!!",
            "p2507945_overall" : 1.0,
            "p2507945_summary" : "Gladiator Costume",
            "p2507945_unixReviewTime" : 1064966400,
            "p2507945_reviewTime" : "10 1, 2003"
        }, 
        {
            "p2507945_reviewerID" : "A2Y0II6CM888FO",
            "p2507945_reviewerName" : "BAB \"BAB\"",
            "p2507945_helpful" : [ 
                3, 
                4
            ],
            "p2507945_reviewText" : "Looks cool but the plastic is very thin on the chest shield, leg and arm guards. The face plate velcroes on as does the shoulder pads which pop off too easily! Every move my son made they were coming apart! Too many pieces for an active boy to keep in place for any length of time! This costume is cheaply made for the price!We were very disappointed in it!!!",
            "p2507945_overall" : 1.0,
            "p2507945_summary" : "Gladiator Costume",
            "p2507945_unixReviewTime" : 1064966400,
            "p2507945_reviewTime" : "10 1, 2003"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is logic error in the code.

This gives you a cursor over all documents in the `p250794_reviews` collection

```
var RvColcursor =
db.p250794_reviews.find({}, {_id : 0});
```

This iterates the cursor, and selected the `productId` from each document

```
while (RvColcursor.hasNext()) {
  var nextRVDoc = RvColcursor.next();
  var ProductID = nextRVDoc.p2507945_asin;
```

This re-queries the `p250794_reviews` collection, and retrieves the first review for the referenced ProductId

```
  var RvDoccursor = db.p2507945_reviews.find({p2507945_asin : ProductID}, {_id : 0, p2507945_asin : 0});
  var nextRVDocUp = RvDoccursor.next();
```

Which is then pushed into the reviews array

```
  db.p2507945_products.update({p2507945_asin : ProductID}, {$push : {Reviews : nextRVDocUp}});
}
```

Basically, you are completely ignoring the reviews returned by the cursor, and repeatedly fetching and pushing only the first review for each document.